# WP Query Results into 3 lists

Tags: php, wordpress, list

I'm trying to run a query that puts my lists into groups of 3. For example...

```
<li>
<div class="col-md-12">Post 1</div>
<div class="col-md-12">Post 2</div>
<div class="col-md-12">Post 3</div>
</li>

<li>
<div class="col-md-12">Post 4</div>
<div class="col-md-12">Post 5</div>
<div class="col-md-12">Post 6</div>
</li>

<li>
<div class="col-md-12">Post 7</div>
<div class="col-md-12">Post 8</div>
<div class="col-md-12">Post 9</div>
</li>
```

Now, I have the below query that works but it seems it displays never-ending results. Should there be a for each call?

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'serivces' ) );  ?>
<li>
    <?php $count = 0; ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="col-md-12"><?php the_title(); ?></div>

    <?php 
       $count++; 
       if ( ( $count % 3 ) == 0 && $query->have_posts() ) {
    ?>
</li>
<li>
    <?php
       }
    endwhile; ?>
</li>
```

Thanks for your help! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out using `$query->have_posts()` inside if condition (the one with the counter) was causing the issue please try this code & see if it works :)

**Edited Code**

```
<li>

<?php
        $count = 0;
        $query = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'post_type' => 'serivces'
            )
        );
        if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            if ($count!=0 && $count%3==0){
                echo "</li><li>";
            }
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-12"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        <?php $count++; endwhile; endif; ?>
    </li>
```

Comment: Hi @nishant the <li> doesn't seem to wrap after each 3 results? Instead it just wraps around the whole 9 items...